# Whenever i try to search elementS in selenium it only prints out 1 out of the maybe 100 possible

Tags: python, selenium

Whenever I try to search elements in selenium it only prints out 1 out of the maybe 100 possible. Here is my Code :

```
Edit: full Code :
*import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ludwigbeck.mitarbeiterangebote.de/")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginData[email]').send_keys("removed email")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginData[password]').send_keys("removed password")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'cbg3-submit').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'cbg3-submit').click()
for i in range(1, 10):
 time.sleep(1)
 driver.get("https://ludwigbeck.mitarbeiterangebote.de/search?s=*&page=" + str(i))
rabatte=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cbg3-list-item--discount')
for r in rabatte:
  print(r.text)
driver.close()
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin*
```

And all the class names are the same. I tried using other classes, but it it didn't helped
it didn't worked. I uploaded a video, link : [youtu.be/GLBHTwRaQ0s](https://youtu.be/GLBHTwRaQ0s) . More informations in the video description

Comment: What happens when you also `print(discount[1].text)`?

Comment: That doesn't change anything

Comment: since you said "prints out 1 out of maybe 100" i assume you have a big list of 'discounts', have you tried to do a `for loop` to get all the discounts you need ??

Comment: Yes, (Code in Description)

Comment: it didn't worked. I uploaded a video, link : youtu.be/GLBHTwRaQ0s . More informations in the video description

Answer (score 0):

Now you code collects `rabatte` only on the page https://ludwigbeck.mitarbeiterangebote.de/search?s=*&page=9. This code goes through search result pages and stops at opening the page 9:

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
 time.sleep(1)
 driver.get("https://ludwigbeck.mitarbeiterangebote.de/search?s=*&page=" + str(i))
```

And after that, this code collects the elements you want only on the last page:

```
rabatte=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cbg3-list-item--discount')
```

Are you sure there are more than 1 element on this 9th page?
If you want to collect `rabatte` on each page you need to insert the second loop into the first loop:

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get("https://ludwigbeck.mitarbeiterangebote.de/search?s=*&page=" + str(i))
    rabatte=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cbg3-list-item--discount')
    for r in rabatte:
        print(r.text)
```

Comment: I have already a Loop here's my Code: (in Description)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't worked. I uploaded a video, link : https://youtu.be/GLBHTwRaQ0s . More informations in the video description.